# Extensible macro definitions

Tags: inheritance, macros, scheme, r5rs

*Inspired by a [comment thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23879410/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-function-lambda-macro-in-scheme/23879575?noredirect=1#comment36794866_23879575) on a related question regarding functions instead of macros.*

Is there any way to extend a Scheme syntax definition so that it can use the previous definition of the syntax in the new definition? Furthermore, this must be extensible, that is, it must be possible to chain the technique together several times.

For example, say we want to extend `lambda` so that every time a function defined with `lambda` is called, it prints "foo" before executing the function body. We can do this in the following way:

```
(define-syntax old-lambda lambda)

(define-syntax lambda
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ args body ...)
     (old-lambda args (display "foo") body ...))))
```

We can also extend this in another way (say, by printing "bar") by doing the following:

```
(define-syntax old-lambda-2 lambda)

(define-syntax lambda
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ args body ...)
     (old-lambda-2 args (display "bar") body ...))))
```

The end result being that functions defined with our new `lambda` will print "foo", then "bar" each time they are called.

However, besides polluting the namespace with lots of `old-lambda-<x>`, this necessitates making a new `old-lambda-<x>` at the source code level each time we do this; this cannot be automated since you can't, say, use `gensym` in the syntax definition either. Therefore, there's no good way to make this extensible; the only plausible solution is naming each one `old-lambda-print-foo` or something similar to disambiguate, which is obviously not a foolproof solution. (For an example of how this could fail, say two different parts of the code were to extend `lambda` to print "foo"; naturally, they would both name it `old-lambda-print-foo`, and voila! `lambda` is now an infinite loop.) Therefore, it would be very nice if we were able to do this in a way which ideally:

- Doesn't require us to pollute the namespace with lots of `old-lambda-<x>`
- Or, failing that, guarantees that we won't have collisions.

Answer (score 1):

In Racket, you can do this with modules. You could create a module that re-exports the entire Racket language except for Racket's `lambda`, and exports your new macro under the name `lambda`. I'll show one way to arrange the code.

The `foo-lambda` module defines and exports the `foo-lambda` form, which creates procedures that print "foo\n" when applied.

```
(module foo-lambda racket
  (define-syntax-rule (foo-lambda formals body ...)
    (lambda formals (displayln "foo") body ...))
  (provide foo-lambda))
```

The `racket-with-foo-lambda` module re-exports the entire Racket language except it provides `foo-lambda` under the name `lambda`.

```
(module racket-with-foo-lambda racket
  (require 'foo-lambda)
  (provide (except-out (all-from-out racket) lambda)
           (rename-out [foo-lambda lambda])))
```

Now you can write a module in this "new language":

```
(module some-program 'racket-with-foo-lambda
  (define f (lambda (x) x))
  (f 2))
(require 'some-program)
```

Note that this doesn't *change* the Racket version of `lambda`, and other Racket forms still use the Racket `lambda` binding. For example, if you rewrote the definition of `f` above as `(define (f x) x)`, then Racket's `define` would expand into a use of Racket's `lambda`, and you would *not* get the "foo" printout.

You can chain extensions: each extension is defined in a module that imports the previous version. For example, your `bar-lambda` module would import the `foo-lambda` module, and so on.

Racket does this internally, in fact. The compiler only understands `lambda` with positional arguments, but the Racket language has a `lambda` that supports both positional and keyword arguments. The implementation of the Racket language has a module that replaces the built-in `lambda` and `#%app` (implicitly used to handle function application syntax) with versions that handle keyword arguments.

Comment: One restriction I note is that in order to chain these extensions, it's necessary for each module to import the previous one. Is it possible to do this in a way which allows the different extensions to be independent from each other, so that I can, say, choose which ones I want to use, order them as I wish, etc?

Comment: It's more complicated, but yes. You could abstract over the definition with a macro, say `define-foo-lambda`, that takes an identifier for the base `lambda`-like form to use.

Comment: That seems to run into the same difficulties as the approach in the question.